# RedBean PHP Перемещение записи

Tags: php, redbeanphp

Пытаюсь переместить запись с одной таблицы в другую с удалением.
Сначала нахожу ее `$info= R::findOne("books", "book_id= ?", array($_POST['id']));`
Потом пытаюсь вставить в другую

```
$book = R::dispense("new");
$book->importFrom($info);
$id = R::store($book);
```

Вот на этом моменте `$book->importFrom($info);` он НЕ создает её (если посмотреть DEBUG), а пытается обновить.
Как можно исправить это?

Вот пример моего кода:

```
require ('folder/rb.php');
R::setup('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mysql','mysql','mysql');
if (!R::testConnection()) die('No database connection');
R::fancyDebug( TRUE );

$book = R::dispense("books");
$book->text = 'notepad';
$book->price = '20';
$id = R::store($book);

$info= R::findOne("books", "price= ?", array(20));

$new_book = R::dispense("new");
$new_book = $new_book->importFrom($info);
$id = R::store($new_book);
```

Debug:

```
resultset: 2 rows
DESCRIBE `books`
resultset: 3 rows
INSERT INTO `books` ( id, `text`,`price` ) VALUES ( NULL, 'notepad',20 ) 
SELECT `books`.* FROM `books` WHERE price= 20 LIMIT 1 -- keep-cache
resultset: 1 rows
show tables
resultset: 2 rows
DESCRIBE `new`
resultset: 3 rows
UPDATE `new` SET `text` = 'notepad' , `price` = 20 WHERE id = 3
```

Comment: `$book = $book->importFrom($info);`, попробуйте.

Comment: Здравствуйте. Не помогло. Тот же результат. Немного дополнил вопрос

Comment: Для чего вам вообще перемещать запись из таблицы `А`, в таблицу `Б`, чтобы таблица `Б` была копией таблицы `А`. Проведите манипуляции с базой `А`, например удалите ненужные поля, отредактируйте, к чему такие "бесполезные" махинации?